# Why does the [new-operator] wiki only reference C++?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just came across a C# question tagged with [new-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-operator). I was curious, so I went to the tag, and found a bunch of questions from different languages, including C#, Java, C++, php, etc.  But the tag wiki only talks about C++, as if this is specific to that language. I'm wondering what the rationale behind that is, or if the wiki needs to be edited to include other languages.

Here's an excerpt of the tag wiki to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

> Use this tag for questions about dynamic allocation in C++ and questions about overloading `operator new`. The [placement-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/placement-new) tag may also be relevant for questions about constructing objects in existing memory.

**Edit:** A Google search on `new operator` brings up pretty much exclusively C++ results. If you append C# onto the search terms, you get [the Microsoft documentation for the new Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator). Searching with Java instead gives you [the Java documentation on creating objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). Note that it *does* refer to `new` as both a key word and an operator. Javascript gives you [the MDN web docs for the new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). I searched some other languages such as php, however I just got programming-related SO questions with "new operator" in the titles.

So I think there is some truth to the fact that it might exist in different languages. My results are by no means extensive, and I'm sure some other people will be able to point me towards some other language examples.

Comment: Programmers ask questions in proportion to how much trouble the operator causes in their programs.  It is about 8.5 times more trouble in [c++] than in [c#], [java] and [javascript], judging from the tag distribution.  Sounds about right, heap corruption is a nasty problem.  That inevitably gives the wiki a c++ lisp.

Comment: It only references c++ probably because a c++ developer wrote it. You can submit an edit (? maybe not at your rep now) that expands the definition to include other languages that uses the `new` object initialization pattern.

Comment: @Will Suggested edits can be submitted by anyone, iirc.

Comment: @Will "You can submit an edit (? maybe not at your rep now)"

Comment: Submitted an edit and had it approved :) Tag wiki still needs more work imo, but maybe by someone a bit more capable than I

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should edit the wiki to include the other languages.  The `new` keyword in those languages looks like the `new` keyword in C++, because C++ is a popular language that influenced other languages.

C++ `new` is a keyword.  I can't declare a variable `int new;`, just as I can't declare `int using;` or `int while;` in C++.  There is an `operator` keyword that overloads operators, as in `operator +` or `operator <<`.  C++ also uses `operator` to overload `new`, as `operator new`.  So we also say that C++ `new` is an operator.  The `new` keyword and the `new` operator are the same thing; there is no difference.

Other languages, like Java, may simplify `new`.  Java has no overloading of `new`, so there is no `operator new` syntax to overload it.  Java `new` is still an operator, because the operator looks the same in Java and C++:

```
Thing *x = new Thing(y);  // C++
Thing x = new Thing(y);   // Java
```

[new-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-operator) probably has more C++ questions than Java questions, because C++ has more complications (like overloading and placement new) that don't exist in Java.  I see 7 highlighted questions under the tag info; 5 are C++ but 2 are other languages:

1. [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/in-c-why-should-new-be-used-as-little-as-possible) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
2. [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
3. [Passing arguments to C# generic new() of templated type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840261/passing-arguments-to-c-sharp-generic-new-of-templated-type) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
4. [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new) [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
5. [Why does the use of 'new' cause memory leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839943/why-does-the-use-of-new-cause-memory-leaks) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
6. [C++ new int[0] -- will it allocate memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087042/c-new-int0-will-it-allocate-memory) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
7. [Why would one replace default new and delete operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-would-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

All 7 questions have language tags, so we know if the question is about C++ or some other language.  This allows C++ to share [new-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-operator) with other languages.  JavaScript `new` also sets the prototype of the object, which raises questions that don't exist in C++ or Java.  Stack Overflow isn't only for C++.

Perl also had the `new` operator:

```
use Math::BigInt;
my $bn = new Math::BigInt('42');
```

This `new` isn't a keyword, but it looks like the operator in C++.  This syntax has some problems and Perl now discourages it, but [people do ask questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955172/what-is-indirect-object-notation-why-is-it-bad-and-how-does-one-avoid-it#32955287).

Answer (score -2):

At a bare minimum, in Java, `new` is a *keyword*, not an operator.  I have no experience in the other languages, so I won't speak to them.

This does raise the question of the validity of the tag at all, really.  But for now I don't see adding more languages to this list as a "good" idea.

Comment: `new` being a  keyword, not an operator in Java is at the very least debatable [The new keyword is a Java operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) and [includes new](http://operator-precedence.com/java) and [the new operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Instantiation)

Comment: The authoritative source about the Java Language, the Java Language Specification, does not include `new` in its list of operators. Makoto's premise is therefore entirely correct. However, I am doubtful the argument generalizes to other languages. For instance, the EcmaScript spec [calls new an operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2).

Comment: @meriton The JLS contradicts itself in chapters 3 and 15 regarding what is and isn't an operator. Chapter 15 not having an explicit reference to `new` as an operator doesn't mean that it's not an operator. Based on everything else it's as much of an operator as other operators discussed in that chapter.

Comment: @Oleg: Chapter 3 is crystal clear, and I fail to see what part of chapter 15 "contradicts" it. If you mean to say that the mere presence in chapter 15 implies new to be an operator, the same reasoning would apply to method invocation expressions ... are you seriously calling `()` an operator?

Comment: @meriton [Chapter 3 Operator table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12) doesn't include [Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) that's a contradiction. Yes method invocation can also be seen as an operator.